# Disable Data sources and transaction managers in Spring/Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am writing an application which has 2 separate set of data sources, session factories and transaction managers for 2 business modules. However when i wish to sell/license only one module, the other must not be initialized or try to connect to the DB in any way.

Is there a way to tell Spring to completely ignore a datasource during startup if it has been instructed to use only one of the business modules ?

Comment: I am not sure if this will help. But can you explore Spring Environment Profiles (http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-31-environment-profiles). You can have two different profiles and call then respectively. Or three profiles with third one having both.

Comment: Why is the module included in the application in the first place?